# load a map of hash - object key pair

Tags: rebol, rebol3, red

Please consider this example where I save a `map!` to a file and want to load it back and access its keys and values.  Its keys are hashes (INTEGER!, calculated by `checksum`) and its values are blocks:

```
Rebol []

bl1: make object! [
        name: "first"
        age: 42
]

bl2: make bl1 []

bl2/name: "second"
bl2/age: 30

hash1: checksum to-binary to-string bl1
hash2: checksum to-binary to-string bl2

m1: make map! []
repend m1 [hash1 bl1]
repend m1 [hash2 bl2]

save %./map_example.ls m1

m2: do load %./map_example.ls
probe join "m2: " type? m2
```

It returns `"m2: map!"`

The file **%map_example.ls** consists of:

```
make map! [
    2749161 make object! [
        name: "first"
        age: 42
    ]
    4111405 make object! [
        name: "second"
        age: 30
    ]
]
```

How can I read the `map!` back to access its keys and values that are objects?

Is `foreach` a way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SAVE` uses an imperfect but more readable format. Use `SAVE/ALL` to preserve all values exactly as they should be (`SAVE/ALL` uses so call serialization format in form of `#[datatype! value]`).

Also, just use `LOAD` and not `DO LOAD` to get the data back. `DO` is not required in this case - `LOAD` converts the string to Rebol values and as it's just data, not a script, there's no need to `DO` it (you can, but it just returns itself).